# jQuery scrollTop doesn't scroll

Tags: jquery, scrolltop

I'm having troubles trying scroll automatically with javascript.
My scrolling area is the body, my js code is

```
$("body").animate({scrollTop: $("#myDiv").position().top)
```

but I don't get any result: no animation and no scrolling
I also tried

```
$("body").scrollTop($("#myDiv").position().top);
```

and also replacing

```
$("body") with $(window).
```

Any hint?

Comment: A quick note to add to this: unlike CSS properties, scrollTop() will not work if units are specified. scrollTop(10) is fine, scrollTop('10') is also ok, but scrollTop('10px') will fail.

Answer (score 3):

`scrollTop` is a jQuery method which gets or sets the  the offset of the current elements scroll bar, but with no animation.

You might be getting confused with the jQuery plugin [`scrollTo`](http://demos.flesler.com/jquery/scrollTo/), which offers the functionality you're after.

You'd use it like;

```
$(window).scrollTo($('#myDiv');
```

Comment: Yes, I've yet tried out the scrollTo plugin, but with no luck.
In this case the code I used is equals to your suggestion.

Comment: *with no luck* is not very helpful. It does work, I assure you. Maybe you can provide a code snippet showing it not-working, or explaining in more detail why it isn't meeting your needs?

Comment: sorry... I continue hittin "enter" and posting
Here is the code snippet:

   $.ajax({
   type : "GET",
   url : projectServiceUrl + "/fetchById",
   data : {
    projectId : $(node).attr("vision-id")
   },
   dataType : "json",
   success : function(result) {
    $(node).addClass("enlarged");
    $(node).css("width", "");
    enlarge(result, node);
    $("#visions").isotope("reLayout", function(){
     var st = $(node).offset().top;
     $(window).scrollTo($(node));
    });
   }
  });

Comment: @stefano: works for me http://jsfiddle.net/Hfymd/. Or even http://jsfiddle.net/Hfymd/1/

Comment: D'OH!
I am sorry, I found out: There was a problem in the CSS. I left a "overflow: hidden" int html element. I removed it and now everything works fine.
many thanks for your help and your time!

Stefano

Answer (score 1):

`scrollTop` is a javascript attribute and you can use it like :

```
document.body.scrollTop = scrollValue;
```

or

```
$("body").get(0).scrollTop = scrollValue;
```

and there's a plugin named **jQuery ScrollTo** written by Ariel Flesler if you want to animate the scrolling:

http://demos.flesler.com/jquery/scrollTo/

Answer (score 1):

Try following code,

```
$('html,body').animate({scrollTop: $("#myDiv").offset().top},500);
```

Answer (score 0):

Note: if you have chrome://flags/#enable-experimental-web-platform-features enabled, the plugin listed above won't work.  It's a known issue: https://github.com/flesler/jquery.scrollTo/issues/92