# jQuery Smooth Scroll not working in webpage

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, scroll, smooth-scrolling

I am trying to use a jQuery internal smooth in my webpage. I have used this same code a number of times without any problem, however this time it is not working. Here is the relevant part of the code -

HTML -

```
<html>
<head>
<title>Geokeep</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="script.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Montserrat">
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto">
</head>
<body>
<section id="section1">
                    <h2 id="h2">A Million Small Things. One Bag</h2>
                    <h3 id="h3">Presenting Geokeep. The world's first recycled and solar-powered bag.</h3>
                    <a  href="#section2" class="button" id="bt1">Know More</a>
                </section>
                <section id="section2">
                    <span id="head">
                        Meet Geokeep
                    </span>
                    <span id="desc">
                        The Geokeep is packed with features that help you do your bit towards the protection of the environment.
                    </span>
                        <!--<img src="Images/DOS.png">-->
                </section>
```

And the JS code -

```
$(function() {
  $('a[href*=#]:not([href=#])').click(function() {
    if (location.pathname.replace(/^\//,'') == this.pathname.replace(/^\//,'') && location.hostname == this.hostname) {
      var target = $(this.hash);
      target = target.length ? target : $('[name=' + this.hash.slice(1) +']');
      if (target.length) {
        $('html,body').animate({
          scrollTop: target.offset().top
        }, 900);
        return false;
      }
    }
  });
});
```

Please suggest an efficient solution.

Comment: Do you have any error on your console?

Comment: Not as such, I am using the same code on a different webpage and over there, it is working flawlessly.

Comment: Define same class on those a href elements that you will use smooth scroll, and then make click on that class!

Answer (score 0):

https://stackoverflow.com/a/10450503/6259383

there's a plugin named `jQuery ScrollTo` can help you
http://demos.flesler.com/jquery/scrollTo/